# How to connect Azure traffic manager with Staging slot of Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-traffic-manager

I read a document ([Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#can-i-use-traffic-manager-with-cloud-service-staging-slots)) and it's says

> Yes, You can create a Traffic manager with a staging slot.
> (Also , attached screenshot [image: Attachment]

But I didn't find any way to do it.
How can I connect the staging slot with the traffic manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an endpoint in the traffic manager, you can select the **External endpoint** for your stage slot of cloud service. Then type the hostname in the staging slot site URL in the **FQDN or IP** option. It will be something like `xxxx.cloudapp.net`.

[image]

Comment: Hey Nancy, When we select Cloud service url with type - Cloud service than it considered "Production SLot" by default. Correct?

Comment: yes, I think so. You must have the staging slot when you would like to connect TM with this staging slot.